# Liquibase won't find changelog files

Tags: java, kotlin, liquibase

I'm trying to call liquibase programmatically.

For that I use the following code :

```
val database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
    .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(JdbcConnection(connection))

Liquibase(pathToChangelog, ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database)
    .update(Contexts(), LabelExpression())
```

Liquibase managed to connect to the database and to acquire the lock, but it fails when parsing the `pathToChangelog` with a `path/to/changelog does not exist` error.

Here is my WAR file structure :

```
WEB-INF
  \  changelog
       \ db.changelog-master.xml
```

I tried

```
"WEB-INF/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"
"/WEB-INF/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"
"changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/WEB-INF/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"
```

and certainly some other stuff, to no avail. It keeps on telling me that the file does not exist.

Am I doing something wrong  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by looking at the source code. The files have to be placed inside the `WEB-INF/classes` directory provided path has to be a relative path starting from there.

For instance, if you put your master file here :

```
WEB-INF/classes/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

the `pathToChangelog` parameter should simply be `changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`.

In fact, this seems to be the default target location for the resources copied by the `maven-war-plugin` for instance.